# Get data from ngrx/store

Tags: angular, ngrx

All works fine with simple types, but I can not manage to work it with objects.

Here is my reducer:

```
import { Action } from '@ngrx/store'
import { RssFeed } from "../rss/rss";

export interface AppState {
  demoData: number;
  feeds: RssFeed[];
}

const initialState: AppState = {
  demoData: 0,
  feeds: []
};

export const INCREMENT = 'INCREMENT';
export const DECREMENT = 'DECREMENT';

export function feedsReducer(state: AppState = initialState, action: Action): AppState {

  switch(action.type) {
    case INCREMENT: {

      return {
        demoData: state.demoData + 1,
        feeds: []
      }
    }
    case DECREMENT: {

        return {
          demoData: state.demoData - 1,
          feeds: []
        }
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

app.module:

```
import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';
import { feedsReducer } from './actions/rss';

imports: [
    StoreModule.provideStore({ feeds: feedsReducer })
  ],
```

component:

```
import {Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { AppState, INCREMENT, DECREMENT } from '../actions/rss'

export class RssComponent {

  state: Observable<AppState>;

  constructor(private store: Store<AppState>) {
    this.state = store.select('feeds');

addDemoData() {
    console.log(this.state);
    this.store.dispatch({type: INCREMENT})
  }
```

I have in console for this.state:

```
Store {_isScalar: false, _dispatcher: Dispatcher, _reducer: Reducer, source: Store, select: function…}
```

instead of my State.  Why ?

I think the error here:

```
store.select('feeds');
```

but I don't know what to pass to store.select().

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I fix it like this, but I am not sure that this is good way:

```
store.select('feedsReducer').subscribe((data: AppState) => this.state = data );
```

Comment: Subscribing to the store in the component is not a good practice. Rather, data can be fetched in the template with async pipe, and this definitely got many advantages.

Answer (score 3):

You can use async pipe it in the template(remember feeds is a observable not an array):

```
-- feeds.component.ts

this.feeds = store.select(state => state.feeds)

-- feed.component.html

<li *ngFor="let feed of feeds | async">
```

Ref: https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple solution that is capable of infering types (so better than using a string) :

```
store
  .select(state => state.feeds)
  .do(feeds => this.feeds = feeds)
  .subscribe();
```

Comment: Subscribing to the store in the component is not a good practice. Rather, data can be fetched in the template with async pipe, and this definitely got many advantages.

Comment: Indeed. I couldn't agree more and I'm all for a fully reactive approach. That said, I focused my answer on giving OP what he wanted, AKA how to fix the type error and didn't want to get lost into a reactive approach explanation that could be an entirely different topic